# JavaScript: select1 on-change to populate specific options (with 2 values) in select2

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using the following code:

```
$("#select1").change(function() {
  var id = $(this).val();
  var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
  $('#select2').html(options);
});
```

work fine and populate the specific options, but how to do it if I have:
one values for every option in select1:

```
<option value="1">some text</option>
```

and two values for every option in select2:

```
<option value="1,1">some other text</option>
```

**UPDATE** for more clarification: 
The first select is like this:

```
 <select id="select1">
    <option value="1">text 1</option>
    <option value="2">text 2</option>
    <option value="3">text 3</option>
    <option value="4">text 4</option>
    <option value="5">text 5</option>
    <option value="6">text 6</option>
    <option value="7">text 7</option>
    ...
 </select>
```

and the second one:

```
<select id="select2">
    <option value="3">some text ...</option>
    <option value="3">some text ...</option>
    <option value="5">some text ...</option>
    <option value="1">some text ...</option>
    <option value="4">some text ...</option>
    <option value="7">some text ...</option>
    <option value="2">some text ...</option>
    <option value="2">some text ...</option>
    <option value="6">some text ...</option>
    <option value="6">some text ...</option>
    ...
</select>
```

If I select the 2nd option from select1, the select2 will be like this

```
<select id="select2">
    <option value="2">some text ...</option>
    <option value="2">some text ...</option>
</select>
```

But, I'm looking for the same functionality when select2 option value is like (i.e):

```
<option value="2,24">some text ...</option>
```

Comment: What do you mean by two values for every option in select2?

Comment: <option value="1,1">some other text</option> and not <option value="1">some other text</option>

Comment: You mean you need to populate select2 by <option value="1,1">some other text</option>   if you select <option value="1">some text</option> of select 1      right?

Comment: yes exactly, that what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below

`$("#select1").change(function() {
    var id  = $(this).val();
  $("#select2 option").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == id) {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
     var arrVal = $(this).val().split(',');
     if(arrVal.indexOf(id)>-1)
        $(this).show();
     else
        $(this).hide();
    }
    });
});`

https://jsfiddle.net/s41rjkhL/5/

Comment: Thanx for your answer, I updated the question for more details

Answer (score 2):

If I understood what you need, you use value for filtering, and when you submit the form you need another data to send

I think the most appropriate way to achieve what you need to put the options of the second select in an array
then filter the array when first select option item selected
then build the second select options

`var select2options = [
  { filterValue="1", text="some text", itemValue="2"},
  {....},
  ...
]`

then when you select an item from select1

`

```
$("#select1").change(function() {
        var id = $(this).val();
        var options = select2Options.filter( item => item.filterValue == id);
        var select2HtmlOptions = '';
        for(let i=0;i<options.length;i++){
            select2HtmlOptions+= <option value="itemValue" data- 
            filter="filterValue">text</option>';
        }
        $('#select2').html(select2HtmlOptions);
    });
```

`

and when you submit you can get

`var filter = $( "#select2:selected" ).data('filter');
var text = $( "#select2:selected" ).text();
var optionValue = $( "#select2:selected" ).val()`